# error C2065: But it is for sure declared

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ostream>
#include "battleshipgrid.h"
using namespace std;

battleshipgrid::battleshipgrid ()
{
    for (int i=0;i < 10;i++)
    {
        for (int j =0; j<10;j++)
        {
            waters[i][j]='o';
        }

    }
}


void battleshipgrid::shotat (position pos, bool hit, char initial)
{
    if (hit)
    {
        waters[pos.getcol()][pos.rowindex()]=initial;
    }
    if (!hit)
    {
        waters[pos.getcol()][pos.rowindex()]='x';
    }
}

bool battleshipgrid::hit(position pos)
{
    if (o.hit(pos))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool battleshipgrid::miss(position pos)
{
    if (!o.hit(pos))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool battleshipgrid::empty(position pos)
{
    if (waters[pos.getcol()][pos.rowindex()]=='o')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

char battleshipgrid::boatinitial(position pos)
{
    return waters[pos.getcol()][pos.rowindex()];
}

void print ()
{
    for (int i=0; i <10;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n";
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            cout<<waters[i][j]<<" ";
        }
    }
```

So as you can see I get the error for an undeclared identifier here is the exact error

error C2065: 'waters' : undeclared identifier

It says that waters is an undeclared identifier. As you may be able to tell, waters has been used in multiple areas and we didn't receive errors for them. If we comment out the void print method it resolves all issues but we need the print method. If you see something I don't please let me know.

Comment: Is `print` a member function?  If so add the scope specifier `battleshipgrid::` like the rest of the functions.

Comment: `void print()` -> `void battleshipgrid::print()` ?

Comment: Wow thanks guys I am so embarrassed. @DoomMuffins

Answer (score 2):

`waters` is clearly a member of `class battleshipgrid`.

In this function, ***which is not part of battleshipgrid***, you try to access member variable `waters`

```
void print ()  // Not part of class battleshipgrid!
{
    for (int i=0; i <10;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<"\n";
        for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            cout<<waters[i][j]<<" "; // Trying to access data in class battleshipgrid!
                                     // but without referring to the class or an instance!
        }
    }
}
```

---

Separately, here's how you simplify a lot of your code:

```
bool battleshipgrid::hit(position pos)   { return o.hit(pos);  }
bool battleshipgrid::miss(position pos)  { return !o.hit(pos); }
bool battleshipgrid::empty(position pos) { return ('o'==waters[pos.getcol()][pos.rowindex()]); }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `waters` is a member variable of the `battleshipgrid` class. `print()`, on the other hand, is not associated with that class.

Did you perhaps mean to implement

```
void battleshipgrid::print ()
```